# Android: fragment causes crash on screen rotation

Tags: android

In the `onCreate` method of my `main activity`, I load the home fragment as follow:

```
HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment().setData(data);  // data is a List<XYZ>
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.bottom_navigation_frame, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

When the screen is rotated, the app crashes at the `onCreateView` method of the `HomeFragment`, because `data` is null.

I am not sure when I should save and restore the state for `data`, which is a large object loaded from DB. I could get another error when trying to save it. So how should I fix the null pointer issue when the screen is rotated?

Comment: it causes only in screen rotation ?

Comment: Please go through [MVVM pattern](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) documentation. This will help solving the crash issue.

Comment: why don't you pass the query params to new fragment and build and execute query in fragment?

Comment: Please post the error message. Most probably this happens because you are getting the ```data``` object from a source that is not triggered again when you rotate the screen, probably an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to Current Activity's property in your Manifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment loses its data when configuration changes or screen rotated.
so you have to unload fragment on onPause and then reload data and fragment when screen changes configuration. here is the listener for screen orientation change.

```
 m_sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Orientation : PORTRAIT");
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG,"Orientation : LANDSCAPE");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
};

SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sm.registerListener(m_sensorEventListener, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```